# Android 3.1 Intent filter host scheme issue with http scheme

Tags: android, http, browser, android-intent, host

In Android 3.1, if my host is http, and scheme is 'www.abc.com', I get redirected to a different page even when I have specified corresponding scheme and host tags in intent filter tags of AndroidManifest.xml. It is working fine on lower android versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the scheme is http and host is www.abc.com, the browser handles it awkward. For other apps such as barcode scanner, the activity chooser comes up fine. In the case of browser, it does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The scheme should be "http" and the host should be "www.abc.com".